# laravel Missing required parameter for [Route: adm.index] [URI: admin/{name}] [Missing parameter: name]

Tags: laravel

controller.php

```
public function index($name)
{
    $academy = Academy::where('won_main',Auth::user()->id)->first();
    return view('auth.dashboard.admin.index',['name'=> $academy]);
}
```

web.php

```
Route::controller(AcademyController::class)
    ->prefix('admin')
    ->middleware('auth')
    ->group(function ()
    Route::get('/{name}','index')->name('adm.index');
});
```

html

```
<a href="{{ route('adm.index',['name'=> $name ])}}">
```

model

```
protected $table = 'academies';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'acadamy_code',
    'won_name',
    'won_main',
    'role',
];

use HasFactory;
```

version laravel 9.2

I want domain.test/name

It's been a long time, but it's not working. I ask for your help.

Answer (score 0):

checkout your Html `<a href=“”>`. You’re passing and array `[‘name’ => $name]` whereas you’re Route is expecting a string `$name`.
Try this:
`<a href=“{{route(‘adm.index’,$name)}}”>`

Comment: i tried it... but. "Undefined variable $name"

Comment: First, make sure you defined the variable ```$name``` in your controller or route and passed it to the view where your ```<a href="">``` is found.

Comment: Then checkout the ```function index``` in ```controller.php```. You passed ```$name``` but don't seem to use it or pass it to the view, instead you passed an array ```$academy``` with key ```name```